# Is it possible to use .random.choice for urls (specifically gifs)?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that will send a random gif (from the few options I've chosen) upon command.

However, it always comes back as errors, saying that the command wasn't found, even tho I typed in ?hug & attribute errors:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hug" is not found
Ignoring exception in command hug:
Ignoring exception in command hug:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lemaia\Pictures\Discord\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lemaia\Documents\DiscordBot\!givebot\v4.0.0.py", line 16, in hug
    embed.random.choice(['https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/414964961953972235/570600544226508821/Server_Welcome.gif ', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGpP4lxGGgK5CBW/giphy.gif', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fvN5KrNcKKUyX7hNIA/giphy.gif', 'https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-cuddling-hug-cute-kawaii-gif-12535135'])
AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'random'"
    embed.random.choice(['https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/414964961953972235/570600544226508821/Server_Welcome.gif ', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGpP4lxGGgK5CBW/giphy.gif', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fvN5KrNcKKUyX7hNIA/giphy.gif', 'https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-cuddling-hug-cute-kawaii-gif-12535135'])
AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'random'"
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready for use <3")
    print(client.user.name)
    print('------------------------')

@client.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'A hug has been sent!', description = 'warm, fuzzy and comforting <3', color = 0x83B5E3)
    embed.random.choice(['https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/414964961953972235/570600544226508821/Server_Welcome.gif ', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGpP4lxGGgK5CBW/giphy.gif', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fvN5KrNcKKUyX7hNIA/giphy.gif', 'https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-cuddling-hug-cute-kawaii-gif-12535135'])
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to use attribute `random` of `Embed` object, not call `random.choice`.
To set image in embed you need to use [`discord.Embed.set_image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready for use <3")
    print(client.user.name)
    print('------------------------')

@client.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    image = random.choice(['https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/414964961953972235/570600544226508821/Server_Welcome.gif', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGpP4lxGGgK5CBW/giphy.gif', 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fvN5KrNcKKUyX7hNIA/giphy.gif', 'https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-cuddling-hug-cute-kawaii-gif-12535135']
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'A hug has been sent!', description = 'warm, fuzzy and comforting <3', color = 0x83B5E3)
    embed.set_image(url=image))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

*`Context` objects has an `send` attribute, which is basically alias to `Context.channel.send`*

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still receiving errors: / "Ignoring exception in command hug:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lemaia\Pictures\Discord\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lemaia\Documents\DiscordBot\!givebot\v4.0.0.py", line 15, in hug
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'A hug has been sent!', description = 'warm, fuzzy and comforting <3', color = 0x83B5E3)
TypeError: set_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'" // My Code:
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/docimageza.py

Comment: According to traceback, you added `title="smth"` to `set_image` call. `set_image` supports only `url` kwarg: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image

[useful pic that shows what is what in embeds](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/221158719025709056/277898421506015232/8xAac.png)

Comment: The code you provided [works for me](https://moeka.is-a-good-waifu.com/4g5NcGP.png)

Comment: Can I ask what program you are using? I've been using Atom, and nearly all my bots have the same issue but the issue doesn't seem to be occurring for others....

Comment: I used Notepad++ for file creation/editing.

Python interpreter version (`python --version`): `Python 3.8.1`

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb, but I can't figure out how to run my program on Notepad++ can you explain further please?

Comment: You dont. You need to run it in python interpreter.

Simplest way to do that - go to folder with file, Shift+RMB in empty place in it, select `Open command line` here (or `Open PowerShell` here, on Win10) and type `python ./your_file_name`.